# Vector and matrix use in RecurrenceTable

Tags: matrix, recursion, vector, difference-equations

Why is this code snippet that uses matrix and vector elements work?

```
RecurrenceTable[{
x[n + 1] == {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}.x[n],
x[0] == {1, 2, 3}},
x, {n, 3}]
```

producing the correct result of {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 4, 9}, {1, 8, 27}, {1, 16, 81}}.

But, simple addition of a vector to the loop stops it from working

```
RecurrenceTable[{
x[n + 1] == {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}.x[n] + {1, 0, 0},
x[0] == {1, 2, 3}},
x, {n, 3}]
```

Expected result that is NOT generated should be {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 9}, {3, 8, 27}, {4, 16, 81}}.

How to fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}.x[n] + {1, 0, 0}` gets evaluated to

> {1 + {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}.x[n], {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}.x[n], {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}.x[n]}

which is quite a mess. A workaround could be the following:

```
RecurrenceTable[{
  {x[1][n + 1], x[2][n + 1], 
    x[3][n + 1]} == {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}.{x[1][n], x[2][n], x[3][n]} + {1, 0, 0},
  {x[1][0], x[2][0], x[3][0]} == {1, 2, 3}
  },
 {x[1], x[2], x[3]},
 {n, 3}
 ]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 9}, {3, 8, 27}, {4, 16, 81}}

An even simpler way would be to use `NestList` instead:

```
step[x_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}.x + {1, 0, 0};
NestList[step, {1, 2, 3}, 3]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 9}, {3, 8, 27}, {4, 16, 81}}

I would also favor the latter because it does not emply any symbolic computation.

Comment: Thank you Henrik Schumacher. I like your second suggestion. What is interesting about the messy evaluation, it should be correct. Am I right? The RecurrenceTable is doing something that I still don't understand. Thanks again!

Comment: The problem is not `RecurrenceTable`: If not all arguments of `Dot` are tensors then Mathematica leaves the expression unevaluated with `Dot` as head. Thus, the following `+ {1, 0, 0}` threats `Dot[....]` as scalar, leading to `{1 + Dot[...], 0 + Dot[...], 0 + Dot[...]}`. This is why in introduced symbolic vectors `{x[1][n],x[2][n],x[3][n]}` in the first suggestion. Admittedly, this leads to quite a crowded code that does not generalize as nicely to other vector dimensions.

Comment: Dmitri, in this case, the usually convenient listability of `Plus[]` is working against us here. So, if you plug a vector to replace `x[n]` in the first output, you get a matrix result, which isn't what you want. (One also encounters a similar problem when trying to assemble vector-valued ODEs in `DSolve[]` or `NDSolve[]`.)

Comment: @Dmitri, I also echo Henrik's recommendation to avoid `RecurrenceTable[]`. But if you really must: `RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == AffineTransform[{{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}, {1, 0, 0}}][x[n]], x[0] == {1, 2, 3}}, x, {n, 3}]`

Comment: Thanks @HenrikSchumacher I understood it now. The messy part wasn't correct. I ended up using the NestList solution.

Comment: @Dmitri You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another fix that might be of interest because it's very close to the original code. Basically, you want to prevent the vector addition from evaluating too early and you can do this by defining a helper function that will not evaluate symbolically:

```
nextVector[vec_List] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}.vec + {1, 0, 0};
RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == nextVector[x[n]], x[0] == {1, 2, 3}}, x, {n, 3}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 9}, {3, 8, 27}, {4, 16, 81}}

Probably not the best way to handle this kind of problem in general, but this is the solution closest in spirit to the original code and it should work for any type of vector operation.

Comment: +1, but note it's `Plus` that is evaluating early, not `Dot`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.